# How to extract the strings within brackets using lookbehind and lookahead zero-length assertions?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I want to extract `0` and `inner_string` from `"string[0][inner_string]"`

My approach uses lookbehind and looahead zero-length assertions.

**This is the regex:**

```
              +--- Look ahead
              |
              v
/(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])/g
  ^
  |
  +--- Look behind
```

```js
var str = "string[0][inner_string]";
console.log(str.match(/(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])/g));
```

However, I'm getting an error.

Is it that possible using lookaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote by **@ctwheels**: "Lookbehinds have little support in JavaScript ([see the current stage of the TC39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind)). At the time of writing this only Chrome (starting with version 62) and Moddable (after Jan 17, 2018) support lookbehinds in JavaScript."

**Regex**: [`\[([^\]]+)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/VLCdsT/1)

```js
str = 'string[0][inner_string]'
re = /\[([^\]]+)\]/g

while(match = re.exec(str)) {
  console.log(match[1])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for those links.  I didn't realize in Chrome is working.